# Can you access Audible through Kindle for kids on the Paperwhite?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, audiobooks

I am looking at getting a PaperWhite for my daughter, and it would be good to access Audible through it, which is a feature of the new Paperwhite.

However, it doesn't say if it is available anywhere I can see.

I know you can do this with the Fire HD tablet, but I don't want her to have a tablet, with internet access (albeit limited) in her room. You also can't restrict the Fire to only allow ebooks and audiobooks at certain times, hence looking at the Paperwhite+Audible combo.

Thanks